# Using javascript/jquery, is there a way to stop the rest of a webpage from loading until the header section is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header (with a video inside), and the header is constructed using a plugin (I am on WordPress). When viewing the website on mobile, the header section takes some time to load, during which the rest of the content fills the empty space. When the header is finally loaded everything realigns as it should (the whole thing takes like 4 seconds).

However, the client prefers the rest of the page is loaded only after the header is there. Is there some javascript/jquery way of doing this that I am missing? Thank you.

Assume the page is constructed this way:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<section class="header">...</section>
<section class="section1">...</section>
<section class="section2">...</section>
<section class="section3">...</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, just set the sections which aren't the header to be hidden. Then, when JavaScript says the page is loaded, set them to be shown.

Comment: Alternatively, set the height of the header section `<section class="header" style='height:300px;'`>` so that it doesn't reposition the rest of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$(".header").ready(function(){
  $(".section1).show();
  $(".section2).show();
  $(".section3).show();
})
```

Comment: Thank you! It's indeed a simple solution. I am accustomed to using the ready function with 'window' and thought it made sense to use for the whole document only. Now I see I can use it for anything.

Answer (score 2):

As Heretic Monkey suggested, use [jQuery's ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

A rudimentary implementation would be to update your section classes to `display:none` and then in your script for this page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".section1).show();
  $(".section2).show();
  $(".section3).show();
});
```

I believe the default implementation of `show()` is to set `display:block` so if you wanted a different value for that property like inline then you can set the value manually through the selector like:

```
$(".section1").attr('style', 'display:inline');
```